# How to reparent components in React or how to make a tiled pane manager

Tags: reactjs

Imagine I'm trying to recreate emacs panes (I'm not but it's the same concept)

[image]

My first attempt was to make a `<Splitter>` component with 1 or 2 children. So it starts off like this

```
<Splitter> // 1
   <Pane>    // A
</Splitter>
```

The user then splits and it becomes this

```
<Splitter>  // 1
   <Splitter>  // 2
     <Pane>      // A
   </Splitter>
   <Splitter>  // 3
     <Pane>      // B
   </Splitter>
</Splitter>
```

You can probably already see the issue. `A` above gets re-rendered because it's no longer a child of `1` it's now a child of `2` and react can't see that it just moved so it deleted the old pane and creates a new one.

Splitting splitter 3 gets to this

```
<Splitter>  // 1
   <Splitter>  // 2
     <Pane>      // A
   </Splitter>
   <Splitter>  // 3
      <Splitter>  // 4
        <Pane>      // B
      </Splitter>
      <Splitter>  // 5
        <Pane>      // C
      </Splitter>
   </Splitter>
</Splitter>
```

I need for those panes not to get re-rendered, just moved. Re-rendering means iframes, video, audio, canvas, webgl, and any other stateful elements don't work. Is there a solution?

Is there a way to reparent components in react? Is see [this issue and it doesn't appear to be possible](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3965). If I could reparent then I could pull all the panes out of the tree, create/delete splitters, then insert the panes back in but AFAICT that's not possible.

Another idea which I tried is to make the panes have their own virtual dom, effectively calling `ReactDOM.render` in each one. Then removing them on unmount and adding them back in to the correct pane. Unfortunately `ReactDOM.render` apparently can only be called once per app. Either that or I don't understand the error message I got which is

```
proxyConsole.js:56 Warning: _renderNewRootComponent(): Render methods should be a 
pure function of props and state; triggering nested component updates from render 
is not allowed. If necessary, trigger nested updates in
componentDidUpdate. Check the render method of App.
```

It appears the only solution is to make all the panes live under the same parent. Since there is no standard CSS/HTML way to really make that work, table, CSS grid, flexbox, none of those will work because eventually you have to nest elements to get the need flexibility and it's that nesting that kills it.

So ... my plan is to manage it entirely myself with one container and a bunch of absolutely sized and positioned children.

**My question:** Am I going in the right direction or is there some other solution like a way to tell react a node needs to be reparented so it doesn't re-render the DOM for those nodes?

Note: I've seen [this example](https://github.com/palantir/react-mosaic). It's using the splitter technique above and has the [same re-rendering issue](https://github.com/palantir/react-mosaic/issues/2) I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rect-grid-layout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) or something like this.

React-Grid-Layout is a grid layout system much like Packery or Gridster, for React.

Unlike those systems, it is responsive and supports breakpoints. Breakpoint layouts can be provided by the user or autogenerated.

RGL is React-only and does not require jQuery.

Comment: Thanks but what I'm trying to create is not a grid. React-grid-layout only works with grids but tiled panes are not a grid. They have entirely arbitrary sizes.